# "Axial" gauge in the $Z_2$ lattice gauge theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, gauge-theory, topological-order, lattice-gauge-theory

I am reading the paper by Fradkin and Susskin on the lattice gauge theory ([Order and disorder in gauge systems and magnets](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevD.17.2637)). In section III. C, where they were trying to introduce the duality transformation of the ($3D$) Hamiltonian form of $Z_2$ gauge theory, they define the so-called axial gauge, which is to require:
\begin{equation}
\sigma_3 = 1,
\end{equation}
on all links oriented along the spatial $z$ direction.
However, they also used the gauge invariance, which is:
\begin{align}
&G(\mathbf{r}) = \Pi_i \sigma_1(\mathbf{r},\hat{n}_i), \\
&G(\mathbf{r}) |\Psi \rangle = |\Psi \rangle.
\end{align}
My confusion is that, if the axial gauge is satisfied, that means for some *physical* state $| \Psi \rangle$, all the spins on the links along $z$ direction are in the $|\uparrow \rangle$ ($+1$ eigenstate of $\sigma_3$) state, then if we act the gauge transformation operator on it, it will obviously flip the spin at the $z$-direction link to $|\downarrow \rangle$, as a result,  $G(\mathbf{r})|\Psi \rangle$ is different from $|\Psi \rangle$.

In other words, it seems that the axial gauge is conflicting with the gauge invariance...
Hope some experts can explain this "contradiction" in detail (or did I misunderstood something?).